# RVM Installation and permission issue

Tags: ruby, linux, terminal, rvm, permission-denied

I install RVM  by [this](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac) tutorial and on the step number 4 `echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ' >> ~/.bash_profile` I got this one error

> -bash: /Users/my_name/.bash_profile: Permission denied

I tried it run with the **sudo**, but I am still getting this error

Comment: Could you post the output of 'ls -lah $HOME/.bash_profile'?

Comment: here is the output: `-rw-r--r--  1 _mysql  staff   417B Feb 21  2011 /Users/my_name/.bash_profile
`

Comment: There's your problem - 'your_name's .bash_profile is owned by the _mysql user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use sudo for rvm installs if you don't want a global install.

To fix a permission error like this, check the current permissions on that file:

```
ls -la ~/.bash_profile
```

It should be owned by the `my_name` user and have read and write access. If it's not, change the ownership like so:

```
sudo chown my_name:my_name /Users/my_name/.bash_profile
```

and any potential permission errors with

```
chmod 600 /Users/my_name/.bash_profile
```

If you ever used root to install your user's rvm, fix it like this:

```
sudo chown -R my_name:my_name /Users/my_name/.rvm
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but if I try this command `sudo chown my_name:my_name /Users/my_name/.bash_profile` - so I always got the error `chown: my_name: Invalid argument` (of course I put the my name)

Comment: `sudo chown my_name: /Users/my_name/.bash_profile` (without the group portion after the colon).

Comment: Try it with just `sudo chown my_name /Users/my_name/.bash_profile`. There might not be a group called my_name (which is the part after the colon).

Comment: `sudo chown -R my_name:my_name /Users/my_name/.rvm` is gold +1