# How to verify if RVM was installed successfully?

Tags: ruby, rvm

How can I verify if a newly installed (by curl) RVM (Ruby) is working and permissions/sources are set correctly on a Debian < 6 install?

Comment: Scroll down and *read* "[Try out your new RVM installation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)" and the following sections after it. Reading the complete installation documentation would have answered this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all installed rubies

```
rvm list rubies
```

Check if the rvm function is working:

```
$ rvm notes
```

Finally, see if there are any dependency requirements for your installation by running:

```
$ rvm requirements
```

[Check this SO question for permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213086/rvm-installation-and-permission-issue)

Comment: [My OUTPUT]: $ **`rvm list rubies`**

`rvm rubies`

`=* ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]`

`# => - current`
`# =* - current && default`
`#  * - default`

Comment: Thx, how do i verify if the sources/permissions are set correctly?

Comment: I included a link to another question. It deals with the permission issues of rvm. Check that.